# C# method freezes entire program

Tags: c#, methods, freeze

I've written the following method in C# for a small Forms program I'm working on, but whenever I try to run this method the entire program freezes.

There are no errors and I've tried to do `for (int n = 0; n<8; n++)` instead of `while(true)`, but that didn't seem to change anything...

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

```
public bool legalMove(int y, int x)
    {
        // Check if the cell is occupied
        if (grid[x, y] != 0)
            return false;

        // Check if there's an opponents circle somewhere around it
        for (int i = -1; i<=1; i++)
            for (int j = -1; i<=1; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    continue;

                int row = x + i;
                int col = y + j;

                if (row >= 0 && row < 8 && col >= 0 && col < 8 && grid[col,row] == -turn)
                {
                    // Now we know that there's an opponents circle somewhere around this space, we now check if it can be captured
                    while(true)
                    {
                        row += i;
                        col += j;

                        if (row < 0 || row > 7 || col < 0 || col > 7 || grid[row, col] == 0)
                            return false; // Outside of the board or an empty space
                        else if (grid[row, col] == turn)
                            return true; // No empty spaces between our cell and another cell of ours 
                    }
                }
            }
        return false; // No cell found around ours
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Answer (score 6):

Here's the problem: `for (int j = -1; i<=1; j++)`. Should be `j<=1` instead of `i<=1`.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I think VS autocorrected it in...